# Headphones don't work on an Acer Aspire 5920g

Tags: 12.04, microphone, headphones, aspire

All the problems I read about were all about the sound not working when they plugged the headphones in.

I have the problem that my mic will work but the sound is still played on my built-in speakers. When I look at the sound settings, it doesn't give me any options for headphones.

I run 12.04 and never had this problem in Windows. I run it on a Acer Aspire 5920g.

Any tips or ideas will be very helpful.

Comment: Have you checked the hardware tab in sound settings ? This lists all available devices, it may not be called just headphones but a veriation on "built in audio"

Comment: Ok well i got them working, but now my speakers work as well...any ideas on how to turn them off and to leave my headphones on?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my Acer 5930g. Even though I plugged in the earphones I hear the sound both in the built in speakers and the headphones.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
gksudo gedit  /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

and add in this line

```
options snd-hda-intel enable=1 index=0 model=auto
```

then save and reboot.

Comment: But this mutes the external speaker for ever!